# No Facebook Comment Box when LIKE BUTTON is clicked on Mobile Browser

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-like, facebook-fbml

Good afternoon everyone.

I have a page where the comment box pops up every time if I am using a normal browser.  But, when I go to my iPhone, the comment box does not appear.  I searched all over Stack and Google, cannot seem to find anything on it- maybe since new issue or not many people testing this on Mobile?  You can test it here to see on iPhone:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

```
<fb:like href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
```

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas - thanks in advance!

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

what i have experienced is that if you have a facebook comment box on your page, then the like button will tricker the comment pop up if viewed from a normal browser.